# How to get A Dependent Property depending on properties of objects of different class in Matlab

Tags: matlab, oop, properties, matlab-class

See the code below:

**Ex_ObjA.m**

```
classdef Ex_ObjA

    properties
        a
    end

    methods
        function Obj=Ex_ObjA(t)
           Obj.a = t; 
        end
    end    
end
```

**Ex_ObjBC.m**

```
classdef Ex_ObjBC 

    properties  
        b 
    end

    properties (Dependent = true, SetAccess = public)
        c
    end    

    methods
        function Obj=Ex_ObjBC(t)
           Obj.b = t; 
        end

        function c=get.c(Obj,s1) % error: Get methods must have exactly one input
           c = Obj.b + s1.a;
        end
    end
end
```

I tried to do following:

```
s1 = Ex_ObjA(2);

s2 = Ex_ObjBC(3);

s2.c
```

Not successful, because **"Get methods must have exactly one input"**. So I can pass the `s1.a` to `Ex_ObjBC` to get `s1.c`?

Comment: You will need to store the object of the class `Ex_ObjA.m` in the `Ex_ObjBC.m` and use it on the Dependent get method. You could make it only one class also. Another solution is to make a function instead of a Dependent property.

Answer (score 0):

`c` isn't really a Dependent property, it's the result of a calculation. Just get rid of the property `c`, and have a method `c = calculatec(Obj, s1)` that executes the same code as you have now.

Comment: I did that define the function like c=getc(Obj,s1) and call it using s2.getc(s1). It works but I do not understand why the inputs have to be like that, one is (Obj,s1) and the caller is getc(s1) - not the same. I know it works but why? Seems Obj is internal input of s2. Thanks...